# numpy broadcasting doesn't work when i think it should?

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

i'm trying to subtract the mean (over rows) from the original matrix, as follows:

```
matrix = matrix - np.mean(matrix,axis=1)
```

(where matrix is 57 x 150) but i get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (57,150) (57,)
```

i'm confused. i thought broadcasting was supposed to solve this exact problem? is there a way to subtract the mean of each row from a matrix using broadcasing, without doing some `expand_dims` and `tile` operations? thanks

Comment: broadcasting can add a leading dimension automatically, but you have to explicitly add trailing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
`np.mean(matrix,axis=1)`
```

Mean will return you one value not two value,Try to use below code...

```
m = np.mean(matrix,axis=1, keepdims=True)
matrix = matrix - m
```

it will work then..